# Prove that $-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))}{x}\ dx=\frac{2}{5}\zeta(3)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polylogarithm

> Prove that $$-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))}{x}\ dx=\frac{2}{5}\zeta(3)$$
> where ${\rm Li}_2(x)$ is the Poly Logarithm function and $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function

Let $$I=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))}{x}\ dx $$
Substituting $x=1-y$ gives $$I=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))}{1-x}\ dx $$
Adding the above two equations we have $$2I=-\int_{0}^{1}{\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\ dx $$
$$2I=-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))}{x(1-x)}\ dx \tag{1}$$
Now we have the integral representation of ${\rm Li}_2(z)$ as $${\rm Li}_2(z)=-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-tz)}{t} \ dt$$
For $z=-x(1-x)$ we have $${\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))=-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1+tx(1-x))}{t} \ dt\tag{2}$$
So from $(1)$ and $(2)$ $$2I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{{\rm Li}_2(-x(1-x))}{x(1-x)}\ \frac{\log(1+tx(1-x))}{t} \ dt\ dx $$
Now I am unable to apply integration by parts in the last equation.

**Edit** I came across this question on MSE [click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109711/find-integral-int-01-frac-operatornameli-2-left-x2-x-right-xdx). I am unable to understand the following equality $$-\frac{1}{2}\int _{\frac{1}{\phi ^2}}^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)}{x}\:dx-\int _{\frac{1}{\phi ^2}}^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)}{1-x}\:dx=-\frac{4}{3}\ln ^3\left(\phi \right)-2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^3}+2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^3\:\phi ^{2k}}+4\ln \left(\phi \right)\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^2\:\phi ^{2k}}+4\ln ^2\left(\phi \right)\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k\:\phi ^{2k}}$$
The first integral I am able to evaluate. I am having problem in the second integral.
Also how do we get the following? $$2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^3\:\phi ^{2k}}+4\ln \left(\phi \right)\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^2\:\phi ^{2k}}+4\ln ^2\left(\phi \right)\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k\:\phi ^{2k}}=\frac{8}{5}\zeta \left(3\right)+\frac{4}{3}\ln ^3\left(\phi \right)-\frac{8}{5}\ln \left(\phi \right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{8}{5}\ln \left(\phi \right)\zeta \left(2\right)$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li_2}\left ( x^2-x \right )}{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109711/find-integral-int-01-frac-operatornameli-2-left-x2-x-right-xdx)

Comment: @MathFail I need some clarifications for the steps involved in the link.

Comment: I don't think the first answer in the post you linked is entirely correct, since $\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1-x^{2}}{4}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\frac{1}{x}dx \approx -0.33569$ and $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln\left(z\right)\ln\left(\frac{1+3z+z^{2}}{1+z}\right)}{1-z^{2}}dz \approx -0.49708$. Your attempt seems correct.

Comment: @Accelerator Then please explain this answer from the second last step. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109711/find-integral-int-01-frac-operatornameli-2-left-x2-x-right-xdx

Comment: What second-to-last step?

Comment: $$=-\frac{4}{3}\ln ^3\left(\phi \right)-2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^3}+2\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^3\:\phi ^{2k}}+4\ln \left(\phi \right)\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^2\:\phi ^{2k}}+4\ln ^2\left(\phi \right)\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k\:\phi ^{2k}}$$ This step and the step after this

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is making you confused about those two steps, but my initial guess is that it's probably the result of using a series to evaluate the integrals in the previous step (using the Dominated Convergence Theorem for interchanging the series and integral signs) and using some polylogarithm properties/definitions. You could start with that idea.